# rkhunter warning /dev files

Tags: development, rkhunter

I recently installed rkhunter and it gave me two warnings for /dev files is there any way to find a list of normal files in /dev?.  I only ask because I ran wireshark and found several ip address which could not be identified. I recently set up my firewall, and had been using a adobe flash chat which I am sure is not very secure or safe (I recently started working on a server, and development with ruby so am trying to operate more safely with this machine).  Thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no 'normal files' in the devices folder.

Comment: Ok, I assume then nothing is wrong.  I noticed all of a sudden serveral telnet attempts to connect, and several known malicious ip's trying to connect, so was worried.  Just making sure, and thank you for your input.